# Making and exporting high resolution (detailed) map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, resolution, jpg

My co-worker gives me a map in JPEG format which is exported from ArcGIS Desktop. When I zoomed it, it shows every detail of the map.

I am using QGIS and I export a map from QGIS. When I try to zoom it, I can't see the detail of the map like the ArcGIS one.

How can I make it visible in detail way like the ArcGIS map?

- QGIS Resolution with 2 point font size.

[image]

- ArcGIS Resolution.
  [image]

Comment: Step one: Ask your coworker about the settings he used.

Comment: Well. I can ask him and I can do it in arcgis. But, I am doing the project in qgis for my self. So, I am here to know about the Qgis.

Comment: So, what did you do and what settings did you use?

Comment: Dear user30184, I am using qgis 3.16 with grass 7.84 in 64 bit of window 7. The maximum resolution size is 3000 dpi but when I try to export using it, the qgis got crush.

Comment: It would be helpful to include a screenshot of your export settings. 3000 dpi is way too high. 350-500 dpi is generally considered high resolution for detailed map production.

Comment: Dear Aaron, Here is screen shoot for the resolution of 500 dpi and another comparative image of Arcgis.

Comment: To me it does not appear the resolution needs to be adjusted, but rather the font size and formatting.

Comment: Dear Aaron, I used the font size of 2 which is almost tiny. But, when i try to zoomed it, still there is no any difference as you thought.  But, when I zoomed the arcgis one, it shows me every detail in clearly as I want.  I don't know why the qgis one is still zoomed in fixed way.

Comment: Are both maps exports from the view/map window or the layout/composer window, at the same scale, using the same symbol and label sizes, and in the case of a layout/composer exports at the same page size?

Comment: Dears, let me answer my question. I got some of the trial solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a 5 months post, and I hope you had figured it out?
If don't, here's my answer:
**Change your paper size in print layout to bigger size.**
here's my example of 4 mm of 'Pusat Kota' Point and 10 point of its text (label). The first picture is when you draw it in A5, and the second picture is in A3.
By changing the paper size, it means it changes the scale of your map, but not your label and symbology's size in QGIS workspace. PS: I'm lowering the second picture to 200 dpi because of the 2MB upload limit.
[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trial solution I got.

I changed font size of symbols to 0.2 and text size to 0.8. It seems invisible for the time being in the map. And, I export it using 2100 dpi which produces 8.8 MB of image bytes size. When I zoomed it, I got the level of detail as I want.

Comment: Yeah, and what unit of size did you use? Points? Map units? mm?